# Splitting one line into two segments in QGIS using Split Features

Tags: qgis, line, splitting

I have a line. It is one feature. I want to cut it in two, so that it becomes two features.

When I use "Split Features", after enabling editing, by drawing a cutting line across the line with two right mouse clicks, I end up with 135 segments at once. What am I doing wrong?

I am using QGIS version 3.10.8-A Coruña.

Comment: I don't know, what you're doing wrong, but my `split features` tool does accept a right click only to finish the split. Maybe you chose the wrong tool? Can you provide a screenshot of the symbol of the tool you're using?

Comment: Thnx Erik, you are right, only the second click is the right mouse. I am using the Split Features tool with the "scissors and the left grey, right green part of a polygon". Now I am studying the thing, it might have  something to do with the fact that the line I want to split is crossing itself many many times... so when I want to make a split on one site, it automatically seems to split on all its intersections.

Comment: Naturally all parts of the line you "cover" with the `split` tool are then split. You have to be a bit careful.

Comment: That's not what I mean. I mean that when the line has intersections of its own, it also splits there automatically apparently.

Comment: I think you should provide a screenshot of your line, and where you're doing the split.

Answer (score 1):

You may be running into this bug from 2011 that still hasn't been fixed: https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/issues/14070 .

Also 2018: https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/issues/27904